# PowerShell Copy files using list of Names

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make a PowerShell script that can copy files to a new destination using a .txt file as a search parameter. The issue I'm having is I don't have the full file extension.

```
$sourceItemFolder = C:\Art_directory
$targetFolder = O:\Work_Folder
$FileList = C:\VbbList.txt
```

The list is laid out

```
191428A1
191435A1
191431A1
191429A1
191430B1
191432A1
```

They are in a column copied from excel*

The source item Folder has many different folders and inside each folder there is variant of each prefix. The prefix being the first 6 characters of each Reference number `191428` and the variant being `A1`

**Sub-Folder Example**-

```
`C:\Art_directory\191428\191428A1 - Family Where Our Roots Grow Deep 1.625x7.25.jpg`


"191428A1 - Family Where Our Roots Grow Deep 1.625x7.25.jpg"` is the full file name.
```

The file I'm wanting to copy is always a `.jpg`

They're about 14k folders in the `Art_directory` folder so going through this, typing in one reference# at a time kinda sucks.

Some of the older folders have descriptions after the reference #'s Example-

`C:\Art_directory\191428 - Family Where Our Roots Grow Deep`

Is it possible to use a txt file as a -Filter or is there another way to go about doing this?

Comment: you haven't described what to do with a file - or what to the text file has to do with anything. please, try some very specific examples. ///// also, PLEASE add formatting around your list and file names. it's quite iffy to read as it now is laid out.

Comment: How many Reference numbers might you have in a file? If it's ten, I would approach the search one way, if 1000, another. For a relatively small set, I would construct a single filer for all subdirectory names, but would loop with a larger data set.

Comment: 25-100+ I simplified the list I posted. I have 75 in my current list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
$sourceItemFolder = 'C:\Art_directory'
$targetFolder     = 'O:\Work_Folder'
$FileList         = 'C:\VbbList.txt'
$extFilter        = '*.jpg'

# $RefNums = Get-Content $FileList

$RefNums = @'
191428A1
191435A1
191431A1
191429A1
191430B1
191432A1 
'@ -Split '\n'  # Sustituting for Get-COntent for testing

ForEach ( $refNum in $RefNums ) {
    $gciSplat = @{ # splatted for readability
        'Path'    = ( Join-Path $sourceItemFolder $refNum.Remove(6) ) + '*' ### or "$sourceItemFolder\$($refNum.Remove(6))*"
        'Filter'  = $refNum + $extFilter
        'Recurse' = $True
        'Depth'   = 1
    }
    ForEach ( $foundFile in ( Get-ChildItem @gciSplat )) {
        Copy-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Destination $targetFolder
    }
}
```

Pipelined:

```
$sourceItemFolder = 'C:\Art_directory'
$targetFolder     = 'O:\Work_Folder'
$FileList         = 'C:\VbbList.txt'
$extFilter        = '*.jpg'

Get-Content $FileList | ForEach{
    $gciSplat    = @{ # splatted for readability
        'Path'    = ( Join-Path $sourceItemFolder $_.Remove(6) ) + '*'
        'Filter'  = $_ + $extFilter
        'Recurse' = $True
        'Depth'   = 1
    }
### -WhatIf parameter included for testing. Remove to execute copy

    Get-ChildItem @gciSplat | Copy-Item -LiteralPath { $_.FullName } $targetFolder -WhatIf

### -WhatIf parameter included for testing. Remove to execute copy
}
```

Just for grins, aliases & hard-coded paths to make a one-liner:

```
gc 'C:\VbbList.txt' | %{ gci "C:\Art_directory\$($_.Remove(6))*" "$_*.jpg" -Recurse -Depth 1 | copy -Literal { $_.FullName } $targetFolder -WhatIf }
```

Assumptions made:

- The folders with names derived from Refernce# are all direct sub-folders of `$sourceItemFolder`
- Files being searched for are items within the sub-folder ( i.e. Search of sub-folder is non-reucrsive)

[About Splatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting)

[About ForEach](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.1) (Statement)

[ForEach-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object)

Answer (score 0):

As for this.

> "Is it possible to use a txt file as a -Filter or is there another way
> to go about doing this?"

No. You'd use that file list in a loop. Read the file and process each line.

```
$sourceItemFolder = 'C:\Art_directory'
$targetFolder     = 'O:\Work_Folder'
$FileList         = (Get-Content -Path 'C:\VbbList.txt')

$FileList | 
ForEach {
    "Processing $PSItem"
    # Other code here.
}
```

As noted by Lee_Daily, you are really not giving enough info, no file content sample, folder info, etc.; thus leaving us to guess/assume. All of which does not lead to a potential helpful response. If all you need is .jpg, then just filter on that for your copy.

```
# Validate your copy action
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'SomeFilePath' -Filter '*.jpg' -Recurse).FullName | 
Copy-Item -Destination 'SomeDestinationPath' -WhatIf
# remove the -WhatIf for thing to happen
```

Comment: The files I'm wanting to copy are pictures(.jpg). The reason I'm copying the file to a new location is to do a batch conversion using adobe illustrator. In illustrator I have a source folder('O:\Work_Folder') that is gone through and various actions are done to manipulate a set of files for printing. We dont use .jpg for printing so they are converted to a proprietary format. I want to be able to copy files out of 'C:\Art_directory' to 'O:\Work_Folder' so i can do batch actions for a certain list of files and not all files.

Comment: The `'C:\Art_directory'` folder has sub folders that are labeled for example `191428` and then inside that folder there are `.jpg` files named with the variants of that file name example `191428A1- "_Description of file_" .jpg`

Comment: The text file is a list of reference numbers that were sent to me for editing but they didn't include the location/link of each file or the full name. I know were the files are kept `C:\Art_directory`. Instead of using the search box in file explorer for each individual item opening the folder for `1914281` and then copying `191428A1- "_Description of file_" .jpg` to `'O:\Work_Folder'`. I would like to able to change the content of the text file to what ever reference numbers i need copied hence why I'm using a text list rather then having specific search terms.

Comment: So the reference numbers in the list will relate to the name of a folder and also a portion of the file name which you want to perform an operation against, correct? @AntonioMcfarren Perhaps using that string from the `GC` with another `Get-ChildItem`, etc. with `-like "*$_*"` filtering perhaps would work. Just a quick idea for postanote but I'd have to dig into the guts of this myself otherwise.

Comment: Kinda, the reference number's first 6 digits indicate the folder or type of art so the "a1" would get removed. The people that upload art just dump it into a "incoming" folder then I have a script that moves files using the first 6 digits to folders with the same 6 digits and if no folder exists it creates one then moves the file from the incoming folder to the `C:\Art_directory\"folder_created"`. Example of the folder created "`C:\Art_directory\191428\"`  then the `191428A1-"description".jpg` is moved into this folder.